# Formula of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I'm looking for formula for series

$$0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+107+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+107+...$$

I knew that e.g. series

$$0+0+1+0+0+1+0+0+1+...$$

can be described by formula

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+2n^2)\:mod\:3$$

I think the solution is taking series with one and multiply it by 107, but how to increase zero terms?

Comment: If you are looking to represent the partial sum in a similar way, note that the period $14$ is composite (unlike the $3$ which is prime), so one way is (before multiplying by $107$)

$$\sum_{n=1}^k [(1+2n)\bmod 2][(1+6n^6)\bmod 7] = \sum_{n=1}^k [(1-n)\bmod 2][(1-n^6)\bmod 7]$$

Comment: Excessively downvoted , new to math SE and very well put together question.

Comment: What is general method of solution for such problem? Is solution with modulo function the only way?

Comment: Could be simply $107\lfloor k/14\rfloor$, where the partial sum from 1 term is $k=1$. Also I made a mistake above; it should be
$$\sum_{n=1}^k [(1+n)\bmod 2][(1+6n^6)\bmod 7] = \ldots$$

Comment: There was a deleted question from yesterday and deleted 3 hours ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4214544/89922

Comment: @peterwhy The questions are similar but different. This one is clearly better (e.g. clearly explains what they are after).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty=\{\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{k\text{ zeroes}},m,\dots\}$. I.e;
$$n\not\equiv 0 \mod (k+1) \implies a_n=0,$$
$$n\equiv 0 \mod (k+1) \implies a_n=m,$$
you can represent $a_n$ as
$$a_n=m\Big\lfloor\frac{n \mod (k+1)}{k}\Big\rfloor$$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). Thus, for your example where $(k,m)=(13,107)$, you could write the sum (despite it definitely not converging) as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 107\Big\lfloor\frac{n \mod (14)}{13}\Big\rfloor$$
$$= 0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+107+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0+107+...$$